# Crawl and Index specific links on specific page

Tags: regex, url, solr, nutch

I am new to nutch so I am just starting my way in. I want to crawl a specific page and under that page, I want to crawl specific links.

for e.g

I want to crawl only http://nutch.apache.org/downloads.html

Under this page I just want to crawl say only *.txt links.Now they can be active links like <a></a>  or they could be embedded in some div like we mostly saw in variety of forums where a link for file upload/download sites are pasted/embedded in some div etc. like `http://example.com/movie_abcd/firstpart.avi`

Here I just want to crawl links ended with .avi.I am just confused with regex-urlfilter because till now I am only using it and I ma not familiar with other url filters such prefix and suffix urls filters.Does they also play important role in the solution for my problem and if they do what will be their purpose.I was searching all over the internet for the past few days for a proper tutorial for nutch but can not find any such.How can achieve this.Also can anyone recommend me a good book for nutch ans solr which have comprehensive practical working examples and description about them and their methodology.

I will be curiously waiting for the answers.

Thanks

Comment: No one has answered yet.Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out my posts, if you have any questions just comment at the bottom and i'll try help you out as much as I can.

[Solr Tutorial](http://amac4.blogspot.com/2013/07/setting-up-solr-with-apache-tomcat-be.html)

[Nutch Tutorial](http://amac4.blogspot.com/2013/07/configuring-nutch-to-crawl-urls.html)